# I'm creating a card game in python, and I'm having trouble remembering how to make sure two lists dont contain cards from the other ones

Tags: python

[image: My Code]

I just want to make sure that the players dont have the same cards in their hands, and if possible a way to remove the cards from their hands to "play" them

I tried to remove things from the list and that didnt really do anything because the players dont have lists themselves

Comment: Please no screenshots of code and output. Text should be copy/pasted as text. You can use the `{}` button in the question editor to format it as code so that whitespace and line feeds are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets and intersections:

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = {2,3,4}
a.intersection(b)
Out[84]: {2, 3}

c = {4,5,6}
a.intersection(c)

Out[86]: set()

bool(a.intersection(b))
Out[87]: True

bool(a.intersection(c))
Out[88]: False
```