# How do I make each player in a card game have a hand of their own and have the game move on?

Tags: python, playing-cards

Related to a previous post, I am trying to make a card game and i want two things to happen, I want the User to decide how many players are playing the game, and then i want it to deal the correct amount of cards to the amount of players, then move on to the next round.

```
## this creates our deck of cards ##
deck = []
suites = ['hearts', 'diamonds', 'spades', 'clubs']
value = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'Jack','Queen','King','Ace']
for s in suites:
  for v in value:
    deck.append([v, s])


def oh_hell_yeah():
  o = 1
  d = 10
  f = True
  while f == True:
    ## this designated how many players are actually playing ##
    for p in range(int(input("how many players?"))):
      print("player " + str(o) + " got")
      random.shuffle(deck)
      for i in range(d):
        card = print(deck[i][0], "of", deck[i][1])
      o += 1
      d -= 1
      ## this is to make sure the round moves on, it starts at 10 cards, then 9, then 8, etc ##
      ##lets say there's 2 players, if i dont include the below code, it deals cards to both players just fine,
      ##but with the below code, it deals to player 1, then player 2 with the reduced cards, and then it ends
      if input('next round?') == ('yes' or 'y'):
        f = True
      else:
        f = False  

oh_hell_yeah()
```

this is what I tried to make and as my comments explain, if i have 2 players, the second player gets ignored for the first "round" and then gets dealt less cards. how would i go about fixing this?

Comment: Why are you shuffling the deck inside the loop?

Comment: In which way is this code related to [google-app-engine]? If not, please remove the tag such that this question is not needlessly in the google cloud collective.

Comment: `input('next round?') == ('yes' or 'y')` does not do what you hope it does. You want `input('next round?') in ['yes', 'y']`

Comment: create a method `play_game()` and in it ask for set up data and then create a loop that repeatedly shuffles a new deck then calls `play_round()` then asks if the user wants to play again. `play_round()` might accept a deck, the number of plays and cards per player.....

Comment: This seems to be the prior post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77181987/12846804
You received an answer but did not accept it, nor wrote a feedback. Encourage answers by adequately following up with your questions.

Comment: @The_spider, it's on Google Colab, that's how it related

Comment: @ScottHunter, I don't know, but I'll move it, so thank you

Comment: @OCa, I'll make sure to check it out again and respond

Comment: @BENJAMIN GILBERT, I am not a kid, I just have a hard time explaining my thoughts, but thank you kindly for the help, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're a kid or something and it's kind of hard to tell what you're asking, but I'll try to point out some obvious errors:

1. Don't assign your variables to a `print`. `print` is for displaying stuff, but it doesn't actually have any value. You want to assign to a string instead, and then print the string, like so:

```
card = str(deck[i][0]) + "of" + deck[i][1]
print(card)
```

Note that the `str()` is needed because the value can be an int (but only sometimes: it would be better if your `value` list was either all ints or all strings, but eh whatever).

2. Let's examine the following statement:

```
if input('next round?') == ('yes' or 'y'):
    f = True
else:
    f = False
```

First of all, you are not using `or` in the correct way. You should assign a variable to your input *first*, and *then* check if it's equal to "yes" or "y", like this:

```
quitgame = input('next round?')
if quitgame == 'yes' or quitgame == 'y':
    f = True
else:
    f = False
```

Second, throw out the `f` variable and use a `break` instead. `break` ends the loop.

```
quitgame = input('next round?')
if quitgame == 'yes' or quitgame == 'y':
    break
```

Lastly, the reason you never get to the second player's turn is because you're asking to move onto the next round before the for loop is even finished looping once. To fix this issue, *unindent* this part of your code so that it is *no longer* in the for loop. It should be in the while loop, but not in the for loop.

Best of luck.

Comment: `input('next round?') == ('yes' or 'y')` could also be `input('next round?') in ['y', 'yes']` in this case. But I agree on the fact that it is always better to assign `input` calls to a variable, as the result is lost otherwise.